# System.err.println() doesn't print in red

Tags: java, eclipse

`System.err.println()` in Eclipse doesn't print in red.

I checked `preferences > Run/Debug > console` and

- "Standard Error text color" is red and
- "show when program writes to standard error" is checked.

any Idea why shouldn't Eclipse print in red?

Comment: Have you installed any plugins on top of the vanilla eclipse installation?

Comment: nope, the only plugin I installed is subversive svn

Comment: Do you run your project with Maven e.g.?

Comment: no! it's a web app with tomcat (if that helps)

Comment: [`System.setErr(System.out)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setErr(java.io.PrintStream)) could have that effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can see this seems to be a [bug that has been fixed in Tomcat 7](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18462) and onwards. I'm not sure if this is what causing it, but it might be:

> Redirection of System.out and System.err in
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start() prevents any other
>   application (for instance an IDE) from redirecting System.out and
>   System.err. It also redirects them to the same output (the standard
>   system output stream) preventing any differentiation of the two
>   streams.